# VSCode debugging VueJs 3 opens duplicates of source files

Tags: vuejs3, google-chrome-devtools, vscode-debugger

One annoying thing when I'm debugging a vue3 app in VScode is that the debugger opens duplicates of my source JS code file where I placed breakpoints but with each file name having **?t=xxxxxxx** appended to its name. It's in these files that I can step through the code. Chrome's dev tools behave the same but I though it would be different within vscode.

After a while, one ends up with lots of this file open as tabs and it gets really annoying.

So if I'm debugging a file call `user.js`, the vscode debugger opens another file called `user.js?t=26484938748` and so on.

I have Vscode configured as below:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:5173",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.mjs",
        "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.tss"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this unavoidable behaviour or is there a way around it?

thank you.

Comment: VSCode is an Electron app.  That means that, despite what it looks like, you are literally running Chrome.  The debugging behavior is going to be that of Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Firefox (with its own vscode debugger) does not behave like this i.e no additional files are open. The issue with FF is that for some reason I cannot expand my watched objects in viscose's watch panel. the object shows up with its > disclosure icon but I can only get it to show something like: Proxy {<target> Object... but no properties. I'm sure t's my config but I cannot tell what to change.